# StreamingClient 409 and 401 errors

Tags: python, api, twitter, tweepy

I'm currently getting 409 errors while trying to run the tweepy StreamingClient. Earlier I experienced 401 errors and have tried removing the project and resetting the bearer token. I've also tried resyncing my clock time to internet time. But my attempts have been useless so far. Is anyone experiencing the same errors or have any ideas for making the stream work?

```
import tweepy

streamer = tweepy.StreamingClient(
    bearer_token='sample_token',
    wait_on_rate_limit=True,
    max_retries=3
)

stream = streamer.filter()
```

Comment: Did you resolve this?